# How do you reliably test if you're in a webview?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, webview

I have gone through a few SO posts on this matter and most seem to suggest to parse the UserAgent(UA) string.

One approach recommended to test for the substring "Version" in the UA. If it contained "Version", then it was assumed that it was NOT a webview.

This seemed to work fine when testing on an iphone and opening a link(website created in Rails) from the Gmail app. However, when testing on an ipad, I get basically the same UA string, and thus the above fails.

Ipad safari UA: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1`

Ipad Safari Webview UA: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604`

How do you reliably test if your in webview in ios? Would the approach be any different on Android?

Comment: One can build a Web browser using `WebView`. So, what exactly is the *technical* difference between an app that uses `WebView` (that happens to be a Web browser), an app that uses `WebView` (that happens to be an email client), and an app that uses `WebView` (that happens to be whatever you are worrying about)? And, why are you worrying about it?

Comment: Basically, there is no way to know if it is a WebView by checking User-Agent because user-agent can be changed to whatever you want.